# Jetbrains: Suppress unresolved variable error (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm

Within my web project I use jQuery.
There is a function registered to jQuery click event.

```
toggleCalculationSelection : function(ev) {
  var src = typeof ev !== 'undefined' ? $(ev.target) : $('form.attribute input[name="calculation"][value="3"]');
```

jQuery delivers an event object with a target property.
JetBrains Webstorms tells me, that `target` is an unresolved variable.

I don't want to turn off this check completely.

How can I either tell Jetbrains to ignore this error in this case or teach it, that jQuery has this property?

Comment: Don't have WebStorm handy, but how about just pressing alt-enter on the warning and choosing "Inspection ... options"? At least one of the options should allow you to disable the warning for that statement.

Comment: No it does not, it allows me to init target and 3 other options, but not to suppress as in some other cases, where it behaves like you wrote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. ev.target is not reported as unresolved for me. Do you have JQuery library enabled for your project?
2. Alt+Enter, choose any of suggestions ('Create field 'target'', for example), hit Right (or press an arror icon next to suggestion), choose 'Suppress for Statement'

Comment: Thank you, it was hidden that way. The jQuery JS is part of the project and is in the JS folder together with all other JS files. What do I have to do, that WebStorm knows about jQuery or other JavaScript files that contain global functions?

Comment: When doing #2 in the anwser phpstorm a single line comment is added as such:  
  
```//noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable```  
  
above the line.